# Stationarity of ARMA-like time series

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

It is well known that for $X_t \sim ARMA(p,q)$ where $\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)Z_t, Z_t\sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$, if $\phi(z)\neq0$ in the unit circle, $\{X_t\}$ is stationary.

Now assume $\{Y_t, t=0, \pm1, ...\}$ is a stationary time series. $\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)Y_t$. If $\phi(z)\neq0$ in the unit circle, is $\{X_t\}$ still stationary?

This question is from *Brockwell* Problem 3.4. I think we should go from the definition of (weak) stationary, but found it hard to calculate the expectation and acvf of $\{X_t\}$. How could we prove it?

---

By the comment from [@Zhanxiong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/20519/zhanxiong), the original question is that $\{X_t\}$ has a stationary solution. It's clear that $\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ can come from one of the root of $\phi(z) = \theta(\mathbb{E}Y_t)$. But how can we define the acvf $\gamma_X(h)$ to let our solution of $X_t$ stationary?

Comment: Which edition of *Brockwell* are you referring to?  The problem you typed is similar, but not identical to, Problem 3.5 of the second edition *Brockwell*.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for mentioning that. The original problem is that "$\{X_t\}$ has a stationary solution". But I still find it hard to build the solution.